# VBA Microsoft Outlook Mail Handling - Adding Another Case

Tags: vba, outlook

In 'ThisOutlookSession' I have this sub which catches a specific attachment. How can I add another condition whereby another particular mail item and attachment is picked up?

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Only act if it's a MailItem
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item

        'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
        If (Msg.SenderName = "Sender") And _
            (Msg.Subject = "Sub") And _
            (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

            'Set folder to save in.
            Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
            Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
            Dim Att As String

            'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
            Const attPath As String = "Z:\Folder\Folder\"

            ' save attachment
            Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
            Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
            myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

            ' mark as read
            Msg.UnRead = False
        End If

    End If

ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [If-Then-Else statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) or [Case statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) to perform a conditional branch in VBA code. Samples are provided below from preceding MSDN links.

#### If-Then-Else Statement

```vb
If dayW = DayOfWeek.Wednesday Then 
    If hour = 14 Or hour = 15 Then 
        Return True 
    Else 
        Return False 
    End If 
ElseIf dayW = DayOfWeek.Thursday Then 
    If hour = 12 Then 
        Return True 
    Else 
        Return False 
    End If 
Else 
    Return False 
End If
```

#### Case Statement

```vb
Select Case number
    Case 1 To 5
        Debug.WriteLine("Between 1 and 5, inclusive")
        ' The following is the only Case clause that evaluates to True. Case 6, 7, 8
        Debug.WriteLine("Between 6 and 8, inclusive")
    Case 9 To 10
        Debug.WriteLine("Equal to 9 or 10")
    Case Else
        Debug.WriteLine("Not between 1 and 10, inclusive")
End Select
```

If your computer isn't on then your VBA code will never get executed.

Comment: +1 for the rather important note about the on state of the computer.

Comment: The most productive time to code is in a power outage and the battery is dead on my laptop...